# Where is core group defined on coreos?

Tags: group, accounts

On CoreOS EC2 instance, I find the following:

```
$ cat /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
core:x:500:500:CoreOS Admin:/home/core:/bin/bash
$ cat /etc/group    
wheel:x:10:root,core
sudo:x:150:
docker:x:233:core
$ id
uid=500(core) gid=500(core) groups=500(core),10(wheel),233(docker),248(systemd-journal),250(portage)
```

1. Where is the `core` group defined?
2. What commands can I use to change the uid *and* gid of the `core` user/group, say in a systemd unit executed at startup?

**update:** this seems to be related to the contents of `/usr/share/baselayout/group`, which does contain the `core` group, but I can't find any link to that file anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the `passwd` and `group` files that you've posted, there is no group called `core` on your system. There is a user called `core`, with user ID 500, and whose primary group has the group ID 500. The group 500 has no name given in these files.

It's possible that group 500 has a name given in another database. The databases for users and groups are configured in [`/etc/nsswitch.conf`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/nsswitch.conf). You can query them with the [`getent`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getent) command:

```
getent group 500
```

[On CoreOS, `/etc/nsswitch.conf`](https://github.com/coreos/baselayout/blob/master/baselayout/nsswitch.conf) contains `usrfiles`, which appears to be a CoreOS extension. It works [like `files`, but looking under `/usr/share/baselayout` instead of `/etc`](https://github.com/coreos/coreos-overlay/blob/master/sys-libs/nss-usrfiles/nss-usrfiles-9999.ebuild). Thus `files usrfiles` means that `/etc/group` will be consulted, then `/usr/share/baselayout/group`.

Users and groups are usually not created on the fly, at boot time or otherwise; they are persistent system configuration. You could call commands like `adduser`, `addgroup`, etc. from a Systemd unit, but that is fairly rare. I'm not familiar with CoreOS, but I highly doubt that creating a user or group called `core` at boot time would achieve anything useful. If you want to give group 500 a name, create an entry in `/etc/group` with `addgroup`. If you want to create a user or a group for your own purposes, use `adduser` and `addgroup`, and don't reuse a name or number that's already taken.

Comment: CoreOS really does seem to know more than what's listed in `/etc/group` as you can see from the output of `id`.  I confirmed that `getgrgid(500)` returns a pointer to struct describing the `core` group.

Comment: Your answer to question 2. "How can I change the uid/gid?" is clear: "don't, just create a new user/group."  But you haven't answered question 1. "How does CoreOS get its information about users and groups?"  Maybe they should really be two separate questions.

Comment: @AryehLeibTaurog Good point, see my edit (sorry for the delay).

Comment: `/etc/nsswitch.conf` is a symbolic link to `/usr/share/baselayout/nsswitch.conf`.  There's a line in there that reads `group: files usrfiles` but I don't see where the meaning of `usrfiles` is defined.

Comment: @AryehLeibTaurog [I see](https://github.com/coreos/baselayout/blob/master/baselayout/nsswitch.conf). It appears to be a CoreOS extension which is [like `files`, but looking under `/usr/share/baselayout` instead of `/etc`](https://github.com/coreos/coreos-overlay/blob/master/sys-libs/nss-usrfiles/nss-usrfiles-9999.ebuild). Thus it means that `/usr/share/baselayout/group` will be consulted.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps someone else can post details of how exactly it works, but [this](https://coreos.com/docs/cluster-management/scaling/adding-disk-space/) at least seems somewhat of a sufficient explanation:

> On a CoreOS machine, the operating system itself is mounted as a read-only partition at /usr.

Instead of changing the uid/gid I just created a new user/group.